# python webscrapping from a website restricted in my country

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

i have this website:
https://fastlane.co.il/

Which is only available (as far as i checked) from Israeli servers (a VPN in israel works fine).
it is a very simple HTML website that i want to scrape.

I want to run the scraping from a cloud service (speicifcally, google cloud).
How can i scrape the HTML using python on a server?
a proxy of somesort?

```
URL:
https://fastlane.co.il/

IP:
81.218.67.65
```

What i want to get?
The HTML code of the website.

What have i tried:

```
import requests 
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
```

Works great on my machines. fails on cloud/Colab

Comment: Which information you want to extract from there and what have you tried?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Is there an issue because Google does not have Israeli servers and you can't connect? If that's the case, check how to use a VPN on your (Google Machine's) OS. If you're asking for a good `python scraper`, github shows ~11 000 results